# How do I make Views fill the full width of their parent in my Android app?

Tags: android, layout, width, parent

I have the following layout defined for one of my Activities:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout android:id="@+id/TableLayout01" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <TableRow android:id="@+id/TableRow01" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
        <EditText android:text="Resource Name" android:id="@+id/ResourceName" android:lines="1" android:isScrollContainer="false"></EditText>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow android:id="@+id/TableRow02" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
        <Button android:id="@+id/Tile" android:text="Tile"></Button>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

The layout renders almost correctly, the only problem is that my text box and my button aren't occupying the full width of their respective rows.

I've tried specifying `fill_parent` for the layout width properties, but to no avail, they still only occupy roughly half of the screen.

Documentation overall for Android so far has been great, but there are a few scenarios like this one where I hit an invisible wall!  Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Try using `android:stretchColumns="0"` (when you define the `TableLayout`) or what ever is the index of the column that you would want to stretch.

For more information - http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-tablelayout.html

Comment: Ah, looking it up in the API, the value "*" (or a comma delimited list of columns starting from 0) worked.

Thanks!

Answer (score 21):

Use `android:layout_width="match_parent"` in your tableRow views.

Now you have different possibilities in your TableLayout seting the parameter `android:stretchColumns` to:

`Value "*"` views will have same width and will fill the row occupying the same space

`Value "0" or other integer` -> First or element corresponding with the integer in a row will fill the row. The other view will have width in a same way of wrap_content

Example with a tablelayout of 3 tableRow with 2 views each:

Without setting `android:stretchColumns`:

```
[|TextView|EditText|          ]
[|TextView|EditText|          ]
[|TextView|EditText|          ]
```

android:stretchColumns="*"

```
[|  TextView    |  EditText  |]
[|  TextView    |  EditText  |]
[|  TextView    |  EditText  |]
```

android:stretchColumns="0"

```
[|    TextView      |EditText|]
[|    TextView      |EditText|]
[|    TextView      |EditText|]
```

android:stretchColumns="1"

```
[|TextView|      EditText    |]
[|TextView|      EditText    |]
[|TextView|      EditText    |]
```

Comment: Very nice answer.

Comment: This must be the accepted one as he's given even visual representation for all possible ways.

Answer (score 9):

Try this in the definition of your TableRow :

```
<TableLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:stretchColumns="1">
```

Comment: It looks like the columns index starting at 0, but yes, this is it!  Apologies, I wish I could choose two correct answers ;)